# Matching Width of TextView Items to Widths of Items with Different Parents using LinearLayout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-linearlayout

Is it possible to match the widths of items with one parent with the widths of items with another parent?

I want to basically make a table where the upper portion contains a LinearLayout with horizontal TextViews that hold labels, basically a row and another scroll-enabled LinearLayout with horizontal TextViews that hold values that are updated in the app. I want the label row to have fixed width textviews and the results textviews to have the same widths. Right now I have the label widths to wrap_content, which is how I want it. How do I get the TextViews in the second layout to have the same width, even when the content will be changed?

Simply put: I want cousin textviews to have the same width, and one cousin to copy the other.

Below is my .xml code.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
    android:orientation="horizontal">



    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/resultsLabel"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:background="@color/cardview_light_background"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Results" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/latLabel"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:background="@color/cardview_light_background"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Latitude" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/longLabel"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:background="@color/cardview_light_background"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Longitude" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/timeLabel"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:background="@color/cardview_light_background"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Time" />


</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    android:background="@android:color/background_dark">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/resultsValue"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:background="@color/cardview_light_background"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/latValue"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:background="@color/cardview_light_background"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/longValue"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:background="@color/cardview_light_background"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/timeValue"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:background="@color/cardview_light_background"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        />


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added LinearLayout nestings that had a main LinearLayout oriented vertically for the table, then horizontally for the columns, and then vertically again to hold the two textViews:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.android.stardustscanner.LogData">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/resultsLabel"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="1dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/cardview_light_background"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Results" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/resultsValue"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="1dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/cardview_light_background"
                android:gravity="center" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/latLabel"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="1dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/cardview_light_background"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Latitude" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/latValue"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="1dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/cardview_light_background"
                android:gravity="center" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/longLabel"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="1dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/cardview_light_background"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Longitude" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/longValue"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="1dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/cardview_light_background"
                android:gravity="center" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/timeLabel"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="1dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/cardview_light_background"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Time" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/timeValue"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="1dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/cardview_light_background"
                android:gravity="center" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="15dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Clear Log"/>

    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

TableLayout is what you're looking for, try this out:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/resultsLabel"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:background="@color/cardview_light_background"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Results" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/latLabel"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:background="@color/cardview_light_background"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Latitude" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/longLabel"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:background="@color/cardview_light_background"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Longitude" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/timeLabel"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:background="@color/cardview_light_background"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Time" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/resultsValue"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:background="@color/cardview_light_background"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/latValue"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:background="@color/cardview_light_background"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/longValue"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:background="@color/cardview_light_background"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/timeValue"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:background="@color/cardview_light_background"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I never used TableLayout before, can I configure it to scroll rows 2 and on while keeping row one on screen?

Comment: Good question. Now that's gonna be the real challenge xD

Comment: If you wrapped the TextViews in the second row, inside a ScrollView, you could scroll each of them separately. Probably not what you're looking for, but it's the best I can think of right now.

Comment: Then with a bit of coding you could probably link the scrolling. It's a nice challenge. Maybe I'll give it a try when I get the time.